# How to find repeated patients and add a new column

Tags: python, loops, date, binary

I am dealing with a large medical dataset. Now I want to add a column that represent the readmission, that is, if a patient has had surgery at most 6 months ago, then that column "Readmission"  will be the number of surgeries that that patient have had in the last 6 months. Otherwise, it will be "0". I will share part of the dataset:

```
Patient_ID Surgery_Date
1838       2017-01-05
1838       2018-04-26
87        2017-01-11
1838       2017-07-06
87        2017-03-17
1838       2018-08-02
87        2017-11-15
1838       2018-11-22
87        2017-02-01
87        2017-06-21
1838       2018-06-14
```

So, in this way, I want to have a new column, in this example, like this:

```
Patient_ID Surgery_Date  Readmission
1838       2017-01-05        0
1838       2018-04-26        0
087        2017-01-11        0
1838       2017-07-06        0
087        2017-03-17        2
1838       2018-08-02        2
087        2017-11-15        1
1838       2018-11-22        2
087        2017-02-01        1
087        2017-06-21        3
1838       2018-06-14        1
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Is it possible a patient appears more than 2 times ? What happens then ?

Comment: I have repeated ID's (which are actually the same person), because that person was under surgery more than once. Then I want to have a column for that "readmission"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an edited answer to the question

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

# Your data plus a new patient that comes often                                                                                                                                                                    
data = {'Patient_ID':[12,1352,55,1352,12,6,1352,100,100,100,100] ,
        'Surgery_Date': ['25/01/2009', '28/01/2009','29/01/2009','12/12/2008','23/02/2008','2/02/2009','12/01/2009','01/01/2009','01/02/2009','01/01/2010','01/02/2010']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Patient_ID','Surgery_Date'])
readmissions = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(df),dtype=int),index=df.index))

# Loop through all unique ids                                                                                                                                                                                      
all_id = df['Patient_ID'].unique()
id_admissions = {}
for pid in all_id:
    # These are all the times a patient with a given ID has had surgery                                                                                                                                            
    patient = df.loc[df['Patient_ID']==pid]
    admissions_sorted = pd.to_datetime(patient['Surgery_Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').sort_values()

    # This checks if the previous surgery was longer than 180 days ago                                                                                                                                              
    frequency = admissions_sorted.diff()<dt.timedelta(days=180)

    # Compute the readmission                                                                                                                                                                                      
    n_admissions = [0]
    for v in frequency.values[1:]:
       n_admissions.append((n_admissions[-1]+1)*v)

    # Add these value to the time series                                                                                                                                                                           
    readmissions.loc[admissions_sorted.index] = n_admissions


df['Readmission'] = readmissions
```

This returns

```
    Patient_ID Surgery_Date  Readmission
0           12   25/01/2009            0
1         1352   28/01/2009            2
2           55   29/01/2009            0
3         1352   12/12/2008            0
4           12   23/02/2008            0
5            6    2/02/2009            0
6         1352   12/01/2009            1
7          100   01/01/2009            0
8          100   01/02/2009            1
9          100   01/01/2010            0
10         100   01/02/2010            1
```

Hope this helps !
This is probably not very python-esque or pandas-esque, but it should work as inteded. I am convinced this could be made much more efficient and readable.

Comment: Yes! That is it! However, when I adapt to my dataset, it shows me this error "Int64Index([7441], dtype='int64') not in index". And I know it is in this line "readmissions.loc[admissions_sorted.index] = n_admissions". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try changing:

readmissions = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(df),dtype=int))

with:

readmissions = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(df),dtype=int),index=df.index)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much @wohlrajh. Can you just quickly explain me why using that line made the code work, please?

Comment: Before that, the index of the "readmission" was simply a range from 0 to the length of the dataframe.
However, your dataframe has probably a different index, potentially with gaps.
Therefore I need to make sure to use the exact same index for my readmission variable as for the initial dataframe.

Comment: Yes! That happens in my dataframe! I have some gaps because I had to clean some rows, so that's why! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hello again @wohlrajh! I only notices right now that this your code is not working for every situation. Check my question again (with a new example), because I noticed that when applying your code to the new example, the new column "readmission" is not the right one (like in the example)

Comment: What in your new example justifies to have 
1838       2018-08-02        2
1838       2018-11-22        2 
?
I would expect the second line to have a 3 in the readmission.